# Emphasize the exponential function in the text

Tags: math-mode, emphasis

I want to typeset something like this:

```
[...] $y = \exp(x)$, where $\exp$ is the exponential function.
```

However, I don't like that `$\exp$` is not at all emphasized in the text. What are good alternatives? Is leaving math mode a good idea?

```
[...] $y = \exp(x)$, where \textit{exp} is the exponential function.
```

Somehow, this does not seem very elegant.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would not recommend changing the font style, I would rather add some redundant information, such as the definition of `exp`, or set it in quotes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$y = \exp(x)$, where $\exp\colon x \mapsto \mathrm{e}^x$ is the
exponential function.

$y = \exp(x)$, where ``$\exp$'' is the exponential function.
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 7):

I assume you want not only "exp", but all letter-based math operators to use a slanted/italic font shape instead of the basic upright/roman shape. It's straightforward to do so -- see the code below. (I owe the code to a comment by @HenriMenke -- thanks, Henri!)

By the way, I'm sure you'll get plenty of advice not to do change the font shape; however, since you asked...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\operator@font=\it
\makeatother

\begin{document}    
$y = \exp(x)$, where $\exp$ is the exponential function.
\end{document}
```

Comment: To get all operators in italics you could use `\let\operator@font=\it`.

Comment: @HenriMenke - Ah, a very good suggestion; I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a message then convey it with explicit intentions. Put explicitly

```
I use $\exp(\bullet)$ to denote the exponential function $e^\bullet$ 
to better typeset the argument without the superscript font size.
```

Don't hide it in the definition clauses if you really think this is a detail that might confuse people.